# What are some IDE options with GUI builder to make a portable GUI applications?

Tags: gui, portable, gui-builder

I need to make an application which is going to portable (windows, linux and Mac). This is the front-end, the GUI stuff. The back-end is written in C++. But now I'm exploring the options to build this front-end. The requirements is: 1) portability across the OS mentioned and, 2) a GUI builder 3) free software, to use and distribute the compiled binaries and related libraries.
Aside C#+Mono, Qt and Lazarus pascal, what are some other options available?

Comment: I don't know a single IDE that supports every GUI framework so I think you need to specify the framework to use. For a free, portable & unrestrictive licenced C++ GUI take a look at wxWidgets https://www.wxwidgets.org/ (there are also bindings for other languages e.g. wxPython)

Comment: This is a local desktop app, not a web app?

Comment: By "portable" do you mean source compatible (ie compile the very same source for all platforms) or binary compatible (ie use the same unchanged binaries on each OS)?

Comment: Delphi nowadays also supports Linux and it already did Windows and OS X for about a decade

Answer (score 2):

I have not used this particular combination of tools for your particular purpose, but I will mention this possibility without exactly recommending it…

---

## JavaFX

[image: logo for JavaFX]

[JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) is a popular [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) toolkit for the [Java platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)). This framework was originally developed at Sun, acquired by Oracle, and recently open-sourced as [*OpenJFX*](https://openjfx.io) (a subproject at [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK)). Development is now led by the [Gluon](https://gluonhq.com) company. JavaFX is the official successor to the [*Swing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)) framework.

You can add download the JavaFX framework, and manually add to your project. Or you can use a dependency/build tool such as [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) or Gradle to automatically download the OpenJFX libraries into your project. Thirdly, you may choose to use a [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) that comes bundled with the OpenJFX such as *LibericaFX* by BellSoft or *ZuluFX* by Azul Systems.

### Cross-platform

Being Java-based, your JavaFX app can run across many platforms including macOS, Linux, and Windows.

You can package your compiled code with a bundled [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) to make a standalone double-clickable app for each of the three platforms. A cutting-edge alternative is making a native app via [ahead-of-time compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation) using [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org).

### Visual editor

As for a [visual GUI editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface_builder), JavaFX Scene Builder is a visual editor developed as part of the OpenJFX project.

JavaFX Scene Builder can be used with multiple [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s including [with IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/opening-fxml-files-in-javafx-scene-builder.html) and [with NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/features/java-on-client/javafx.html).

Be aware that you have two alternatives to using a visual tool: Writing the interface declaratively via [*FXML*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FXML), and writing the interface procedurally using Java code. I prefer the last one, having been surprised how well it works to simply make calls in Java to define a layout and add widgets.

### Interoperating with C++ code

You can [call C++ code from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7593334/642706).

- [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) is the classic vehicle.
- [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) was later developed to be an easier route.

### Cost

All the mentioned products are available free-of-cost.

---

## Xojo

[image: Xojo logo]

An entirely different solution would be [Xojo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xojo). Xojo is a commercial product that includes:

- a modern object-oriented programming language
- native compilers for multiple platforms including macOS, Linux, and Windows
- a visual GUI editor

This might meet your needs, though it does come with a fee, and I do not know the specifics of calling your C++ backend code.